# Using oxyplot to plot graphs on form (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oxyplot

I need to draw some graphs for a project I am working on and at the moment am trying to use the oxyplot library to draw a graph on the windows form. The code I have written at the moment is:

```
Dim Graph As OxyPlot.PlotModel = New OxyPlot.PlotModel
    Graph.Title = "Test"
    Dim s1 As OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries
    s1.Points.Add(New OxyPlot.DataPoint(2, 7))
    s1.Points.Add(New OxyPlot.DataPoint(7, 9))
    s1.Points.Add(New OxyPlot.DataPoint(9, 4))

    Graph.Series.Add(s1)


End Sub
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here to actually plot a graph on the form. Also is there any oxyplot documentation on plotting in forms specifically for vb.net as the only ones I can seem to find are for c#

Answer (score 0):

I have also struggled finding a way to implement Oxyplot on windows form in VB.NET.

The simplest way remains **adding the plot to the windows form through the toolbox**. For that, you have to add the Oxyplot control to the toolbox first (e.g. Tools > Choose Toolbox Items...) and on the .NET component tab browse and find the OxyPlot.WindowsForms.dll in your project bin folder.
This step used to fail a long time for me as no control could be found in the dll, but I achieved it after uninstalling the Oxyplot packages and putting them back. 
Once done, you should be able to add a new "PlotView1" PlotView instance on your form from the toolbox by drag and drop. Place it, resize it, set it up the way you want.

Then on the **Form1.Designer.vb**, I have  added few lines on the  InitializeComponent() sub between the "Plotview1" and "Form1" blocks to add your series and to have something showing up:

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.PlotView1 = New OxyPlot.WindowsForms.PlotView()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'PlotView1
    '
    Me.PlotView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
    Me.PlotView1.Name = "PlotView1"
    Me.PlotView1.PanCursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand
    Me.PlotView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(260, 238)
    Me.PlotView1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.PlotView1.Text = "PlotView1"
    Me.PlotView1.ZoomHorizontalCursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeWE
    Me.PlotView1.ZoomRectangleCursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNWSE
    Me.PlotView1.ZoomVerticalCursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.SizeNS

    '
    'Sample Series
    '
    plotmod.Title = "Test"
    s1.Points.Add(New OxyPlot.DataPoint(2, 7))
    s1.Points.Add(New OxyPlot.DataPoint(7, 9))
    s1.Points.Add(New OxyPlot.DataPoint(9, 4))
    plotmod.Series.Add(s1)
    Me.PlotView1.Model = plotmod

    '
    'Form1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 262)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.PlotView1)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.Text = "Window"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
```

As I am not a regular programmer, I expect there are more appropriate ways of coding this sample.